# How can I create and save a 3D model of a graph?

Tags: javascript, swift, 3d, augmented-reality

I currently have a webpage where I use user input to create and display an interactive 3D graph using Plotly.

Now I’m thinking of including an AR element (similar to the Geogebra AR app) where the graph is an AR object, however first I need to auto create a 3D model of the graph. Is there any way I can grab this 3D model straight from Plotly (given that the the graph is already 3D and interactive, doesn’t that suggest there exists enough information for a 3D model?)

If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about creating a model which can then be shown on a phone app or perhaps even on a mobile browser?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Note - Ideally I would also like to make models of a p5.js animation as well but thought it best to take one step at a time...